# How to use \psaxes with trigonometric labels of even multiples of π/3?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

### Constraints

- I only want to use `\psaxes` rather than multiple calls of `\psxTick`, `\rput`, `\uput`.
- I want to have trigonometric labels with even multiple of `π/3`.

### My attempts

As usual, we can have trigonometric labels of multiple of `π/3` without any problem.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1) 
    \psaxes[dx=\PiOverThree](0,0)(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1)
\end{pspicture}
```

In order to get even multiple of `π/3`, I changed `dx=\TwoPiOverThree` as follows.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1) 
    \psaxes[dx=\TwoPiOverThree](0,0)(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1)
\end{pspicture}
```

However, this change should be followed by setting `Dx=\TwoPiOverThree`.
Unfortunately, setting `Dx` produces errors (that you can see by compiling my MWE below).

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\PiOverThree{1.047197}
\def\TwoPiOverThree{2.094395}

\psset
{   
    xtrigLabels,
    trigLabelBase=3,
    xunit=\PiOverThree,
}


\begin{document}
\section*{With $\pi/3$ step (completed)}

\begin{pspicture}(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1) 
    \psaxes[dx=\PiOverThree](0,0)(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1)
\end{pspicture}

\section*{With $2\pi/3$ step (uncompleted)}

\begin{pspicture}(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1) 
    \psaxes[dx=\TwoPiOverThree](0,0)(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1)
\end{pspicture}


% does not compile
%\begin{pspicture}(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1)    
    %\psaxes[dx=\TwoPiOverThree,Dx=\TwoPiOverThree](0,0)(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1)
%\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Bonus Questions

How to set different `trigLabelBase` for `x`-axis and `y`-axis? I cannot find `xtrigLabelBase` and `ytrigLabelBase` in the `pst-plot` documentation. They might not be implemented yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 \psaxes[dx=\TwoPiOverThree,Dx=2](0,0)(-\psPiTwo,-1)(\psPiTwo,1)
```